# Paste logical conditions in R

Tags: r

I have now rewriten my problem to make it clearer

I want to replace a condition like this where var is a variable in dataframe (dataframe$var) with a paste or other solution as I do have so many condition values(?) (a, b and c  in my example).

```
subdataframe<-dataframe[var=="a"|var=="b"|var=="c",]
```

I have tried to make a list(?) of the condtion values.

```
sample<-c("a","b","c")
```

And to then use paste to make the logical condition

```
subdataframe<-dataframe[paste("var",sample,sep="==",collapse="|"),]
```

But that doesn't work

Help please =)

Marcus

Comment: What you describe goes by the name `eval` in languages that support it (dunno if R has it) - and over there, they have a saying: If `eval` is the answer, you are asking the wrong question.

Comment: @delnan it's actually `parse`, not `eval` (see my answer for the quote). +1 for being so close! ;-)

Comment: @Joshua: I saw you answer afterwards and was surprised I was so close :) Especially since I know close to nothing about R, and I'm pretty sure I that quote is older than 2005.

Comment: @delnan I've seen fortune(106) quoted most often.  I wouldn't know if there was something pre-2005 though.  I agree that the same advice is true for `eval`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Heed fortune(106):

```
> fortune(106)

If the answer is parse() you should usually rethink the question.
   -- Thomas Lumley
      R-help (February 2005)
```

So I would encourage you to rethink what you're trying to do...

I would guess that you could use `match` or `%in%` to achieve your desired result, but you haven't told us what you're trying to do.

```
> sample <- c("a","b","c")
> var <- c("a","d","c")
> eval(parse(text=paste("var==",sample,"",sep="'",collapse="|")))
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
> var %in% sample
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: Looks like he's subsetting, so he'd just write `object[var %in% sample, ]` to get, e.g., the rows of a data frame where var matches an item in the list.

Comment: Yes. That's what I am trying to do. In my case I am trying to extract data from a a panel data set byt I just vant certain years and certain enteties (countries in my case). And I want to extract the enteties I have in a vector, in this case sample.

Answer (score 1):

Joshua is right in questioning the use of parse.

Still, here's the answer to your question:

```
 paste("var==\"",sample, "\"",sep="",collapse="|")
```

This will get you the desired string, inculding quotes.

Comment: It was, before he updated his question. See revision 1 of the question.

Comment: I removed my comment. You are right, in 1st revision the main question is how to paste with quotes (but treating as condition is there too ;)). Just to add to your answer: instead of using `"\""` you could use `shQuotes`: `paste("var==",shQuote(sample), sep="",collapse="|")`.