# splitting up ranges

Tags: r

Say I have some ranges represented by start coordinates `start<-c(1,2,3)` and end coordiantes `end<-c(4,5,4) ;ranges<-data.frame(start,end)` How can I split this up into one length intervals? 
i.e. I want

this

```
   starts ends
1      1    4
2      2    5
3      3    4
```

to be transformed into this:

```
   starts ends
1      1    2      |
2      3    4     <-end of original first interval
3      2    3      |
4      4    5     <-end of original second interval
5      3    4     <-end of original third interval
```

right now I have a for loop iterating through the list and creating a sequence sequence that goes from start to end but this loop takes a very long time to execute for long lists of ranges.

Comment: ...why don't you post your code, it might be a small detail that makes all the difference in speed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try creating text for the vectors, `parse`-ing and `eval`-uating and then using a `matrix` to create the `data.frame`:

```
txt <- paste("c(",paste(ranges$start,ranges$end,sep=":",collapse=","),")",sep="")

> txt
[1] "c(1:4,2:5,3:4)"

vec <- eval(parse(text=txt))
> vec
 [1] 1 2 3 4 2 3 4 5 3 4

mat <- matrix(vec,ncol=2,byrow=T)
> data.frame(mat)
  X1 X2
1  1  2
2  3  4
3  2  3
4  4  5
5  3  4
```

Comment: +1 for innovative thinking! This takes 0.94 secs on my machine compared to my solution's 1.6 secs...

Comment: excellent! do you know if completing a parse takes less time than a loop? EDIT: @Tommy thanks for confirming it doe

Comment: For the record, I don't think this fortune about using `parse` applies here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339077/paste-logical-conditions-in-r/4339192#4339192 ...but I tend to try to use `do.call` instead to avoid that issue.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way. It's a "glorified for-loop" in the disguise of `lapply` on a sequence.

```
# Your sample data
ranges<-data.frame(start=c(1,2,3),end=c(4,5,4))

# Extract the start/end columns         
start <- ranges$start
end <- ranges$end
# Calculate result data
res <- lapply(seq_along(start), function(i) start[i]+seq(0, end[i]-start[i]))
# Make it into a data.frame by way of a matrix (which has a byrow argument)
newRanges <- as.data.frame( matrix(unlist(res), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE, dimnames=list(NULL, names(ranges))) )
```

Which gives the correct result:

```
> newRanges
  start end
1     1   2
2     3   4
3     2   3
4     4   5
5     3   4
```

And then time it on a bigger problem:

```
n <- 1e5
start <- sample(10, n, replace=TRUE)
end <- start + sample( 3, n, replace=TRUE)*2-1
system.time( newRanges <- as.data.frame( matrix(unlist(lapply(seq_along(start), function(i) start[i]+seq(0, end[i]-start[i]))), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE) ) )
```

This takes about 1.6 seconds on my machine. Good enough?

...The trick is to work on the vectors directly instead of on the data.frame. And then build the data.frame at the end.

**Update** @Ellipsis... commented that `lapply` is no better than a for-loop. Let's see:

```
system.time( a <- unlist(lapply(seq_along(start), function(i) start[i]+seq(0, end[i]-start[i]))) ) # 1.6 secs

system.time( b <- {
  res <- vector('list', length(start))
  for (i in seq_along(start)) {   
    res[[i]] <- start[i]+seq(0, end[i]-start[i])
  }
  unlist(res) 
}) # 1.8 secs
```

So, not only is the for-loop about 12% slower in this case, it is also much more verbose...

**UPDATE AGAIN!**

@Martin Morgan suggested using `Map`, and it is indeed the fastest solution yet - faster than `do.call` in my other answer. Also, by using `seq.int` my first solution is also much faster:

```
# do.call solution: 0.46 secs 
system.time( matrix(do.call('c', lapply(seq_along(start), function(i) call(':', start[i], end[i]))), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE) )

# lapply solution: 0.42 secs   
system.time( matrix(unlist(lapply(seq_along(start), function(i) start[[i]]+seq.int(0L, end[[i]]-start[[i]]))), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE) )

# Map solution: 0.26 secs   
system.time( matrix(unlist(Map(seq.int, start, end)), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE) )
```

Comment: lapply is no better than a for loop

Comment: Maybe `Map(seq, start, end)` instead of `lapply`, or `with(ranges, Map(seq, start, end))` to avoid explicit extraction of starts and ends.

Comment: @MartinMorgan - Excellent idea! `Map` is indeed faster than `lapply` here (around 20% faster).

Comment: ...but it seems my other answer using `do.call` is still the fastest. Even if it still has only 0 votes :(

Comment: try `seq.int` for speed, with `USE.NAMES=FALSE` for `Map`

Comment: @MartinMorgan - Great idea. Didn't see any difference when using `USE.NAMES=FALSE` though. Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another answer based on @James great solution. It avoids paste and parse and is a little bit faster:

```
vec <- do.call('c', lapply(seq_along(start), function(i) call(':', start[i], end[i])))
mat <- matrix(vec,ncol=2,byrow=T)
```

Timing it:

```
set.seed(42)
n <- 1e5
start <- sample(10, n, replace=TRUE)
end <- start + sample( 3, n, replace=TRUE)*2-1

# @James code: 6,64 secs
system.time({
  for(i in 1:10) {
    txt <- paste("c(",paste(start,end,sep=":",collapse=","),")",sep="")
    vec <- eval(parse(text=txt))
    mat <- matrix(vec,ncol=2,byrow=T)
  }
})

# My variant: 5.17 secs
system.time({
  for(i in 1:10) {
    vec <- do.call('c', lapply(seq_along(start), function(i) call(':', start[i], end[i])))
    mat <- matrix(vec,ncol=2,byrow=T)
  }
})
```

Comment: The great thing about james' code is that it doesn't need a for loop at all.

Comment: @Ellipsis... Well, neither does this one. It uses `lapply` :-) ...and end up being somewhat faster. The number of characters to type is pretty much the same too. So this is more efficient even on a time/character basis.

Comment: ...and it avoids objections against using `parse`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339077/paste-logical-conditions-in-r/4339192#4339192